# Can you import data into multiple tables in a single request via the bigquery API?

Tags: google-bigquery

i have read the documentation regarding constructing a multipart request. is it possible to send more than just one load specification along with its payload by specifying multiple multipart boundaries in the same request body? if so, does it count against import quota per table or per request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ... only one table can be imported to per import request (you can, of course, do multiple imports in parallel by creating multiple requests).

Comment: Thanks Jordan. It would be an interesting use case because then you could build and destroy databases per client in a saas application for instance. You still could, but it wouldn't scale past the 1000 import request per day quota unless each import could update more than one table. Of course, I say that without the faintest clue of what it would take on the bigquery side.

Comment: The 1k imports / day quota is there mostly to prevent people from doing huge numbers of tiny appends, which would waste a lot of bigquery resources. If you have a real use case that requires more imports, if you fill out the form here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/feedback someone may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks again Jordan. I filled out the form and put this: I'd like to be able to create separate tables for each of my SaaS app users to make things more maintainable. For example, I'd like a table per account, so when I want to do a delete or rebuild of that account's data, it's manageable. But currently, there exists a 1000 a day limit on how much I can import. That means that if I have 1000 users, I can only update each of their tables at max once per day. This obviously doesn't scale. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnWheeler Did you find a solution for your usecase? I'm planning similar one and see 1500/day limit is a blocker. Can you please share how you solved it?